# How to store websocket id in Gorilla using Redis for accessing the socket connection across the processes

Tags: go, websocket, redis, gorilla

I would like to know the best way to store the websocket client id or connection in Redis. I am not building a chat app so I do not need to broadcast but send messages to specific websockets.

Need help.

Comment: It is not possible to store a Gorilla websocket connection in a database.  It is not possible to pass a Gorilla websocket connection to another process.

Comment: That means we can only use the socket connection in the same instance and within same process?

Comment: Is there any other alternative?

Comment: A websocket connection is only useable within a single process.  Route messages to the process where the connection is terminated.